# What does Gandalf think about how Frodo goes to Mordor

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-two-towers

In *The Two Towers*, what does Gandalf think about how Frodo goes to Mordor? I mean, he knew that obviously Frodo didn't know the road to the Mordor, so how can he say "Each day Frodo brings it closer to the fires of Mount Doom"?

[image: Screenshot with Gandalf, subtitled: "Each day Frodo brings it closer to the fires of Mount Doom"]

Comment: Like most managers, he's just assuming that Frodo's getting on with his job instead of sitting around Rivendell having a pedicure and learning to play the harp.

Comment: @Richard but even when Aragorn did let Frodo go , he knew that Frodo had not known the road and the same situation is also here , so how can they assume Frodo will find the road ? Actually , if Frodo was sitting in Rivendell , it would have been much safer for Frodo and especially the ring.Sending Frodo to Mordor without saying how he should go is increase the chance of being found of the ring , isn't it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gandalf hopes in the providence of Eru Ilúvatar.  He doesn't know specifically how Frodo will get to Mordor (although Frodo might know the general direction by studying maps in Rivendell), but hopes that Eru -- who just brought Gandalf back to life to finish his mission (which is to defeat Sauron) -- will guide Frodo there through some means.

We can see that in these quotes:

> "Behind that there was something else at work, beyond any design of the Ring-maker. I can put it no plainer than by saying that Bilbo was meant to find the Ring, and not by its maker. In which case you also were meant to have it. And that maybe an encouraging thought."

and

> "My heart tells me that [Gollum]  has some part to play yet, for good or ill."

Gandalf tells Pippin that he doesn't have much hope that the plan will succeed.  But since no one could think of a better plan, he does everything he can to help it succeed.  If Frodo had already been caught at the point and the plan definitely failed, Gandalf would have probably said the same thing.

Comment: Where and when does Gandalf said the "I don't have much hope that the plan will succeed" ?

Comment: Also , these you said may excuse for Gandalf , but how about Aragorn ? he also knew that Frodo don't know the road ?

Comment: From this exchange in ROTK (this is from the book, but there was similar dialog in the movie, IIRC):

 "Tell me,’ he said, ‘is there any hope? For Frodo, I mean; or at least mostly for Frodo.’

 Gandalf put his hand on Pippin’s head. ‘There never was much hope,’ he answered. ‘Just a fool’s hope, as I have been told.'"

Comment: I'm not sure how confident Aragorn is in Frodo's chances, but any hope he has seems to be secondhand hope, from Gandalf.  He's known Gandalf for many years and knows that he's a powerful being sent to Middle-Earth to help the free peoples fight Sauron, so if Gandalf has hope, Aragorn would have some as well.